# Store data in Outlook Addin for each user, then query it for all users

Tags: exchange-server, outlook-addin

Is there a way for an Outlook add-in to store some data for each outlook user, then an Exchange admin can query this data for *all users* at once?

If I store the data into `Item.UserPorperties` or `Folder.StorageItems`, Exchange Admins will not have access to them. And I prefer not to use an external DB.

My goal is for Exchange Admin to run a script or an app that gets the custom data for each user. something like:

```
Email      Tasks Completed    Some Data
-------    ----------------   ---------
x@x.com        5               25
```

I plan to use EWS Managed API or Exchange Management Shell to query the Data. I am just not sure where is the ideal place to store it from the Outlook Add-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is just use a central repository eg a public folder or a shared mailbox that all use have rights to create Items in and then just create/modify one item in the Folder/Mailbox for each user with your plugin. Then your Admin/App can just query all the Items in that Mailbox/Folder (this is way the Free/Busy information used to work via a shared public folder in Exchange)

Cheers
Glen